# How to add a label to each marking on folium map

Tags: python, dataframe, folium

I am trying to map some fire fronts and label them according to their index. Basically I want the first point to be labeled 1, next 2... How do I add it to this code?

```
import folium
BBox = [(37, 26),(39.8,28.8)]
m = folium.Map()
m.fit_bounds(BBox)
for index, row in fire.iterrows():
    depot_node = (row['latitude'], row['longitude'])            
    line = folium.CircleMarker(location=depot_node,
                               radius=10,    
                               color='red',
                               fill_color ='red',
                               fill_opacity=0.7,
                              ).add_to(m)
```

This is the data:

[image: fire data]

Answer (score 1):

You can add text in html format with the marker icon function. The position of the text is set by the icon anchor. I manually adjusted it to be included in the circle.

```
import folium
from folium.features import DivIcon

BBox = [(37, 26),(39.8,28.8)]
m = folium.Map(min_zoom=8)
m.fit_bounds(BBox)
for index, row in fire.iterrows():
    depot_node = (row['latitude'], row['longitude'])            
    folium.CircleMarker(location=depot_node,
                               radius=10,    
                               color='red',
                               fill_color ='red',
                               fill_opacity=0.7,
                              ).add_to(m)
    folium.map.Marker(depot_node,
                      icon=DivIcon(
                          icon_size=(30,30),
                          icon_anchor=(5,14),
                          html=f'<div style="font-size: 14pt">%s</div>' % str(index),
                      )
                     ).add_to(m)
    
m
```

[image]